# Aurelia bindable value converters (boolean etc.)

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have this property decorator, which runs the property value through a converter, so I can use `some-bindable-value="true"` inside the view template:

```
function valueConverter(converter: Function) {
    return (target: any, key: string) => {


        let definition = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
        if (definition) {
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
                get: definition.get,
                set: newValue => {
                    definition.set(converter(newValue));
                },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        } else {
            Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
                get: function () {
                    return this['__' + key];
                },
                set: function (newValue) {
                    this['__' + key] = converter(newValue);
                },
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
}

class App {
    @valueConverter(value => value == 'true') public someBooleanValue;

    constructor() {
        this.someBooleanValue = 'false';
        console.log(this.someBooleanValue) // false

        this.someBooleanValue = 'true';
        console.log(this.someBooleanValue) // true
    }

}
```

This works fine as long as I don't also use the `@bindable` decorator (which makes it completely pointless). I'm new to decorators and am not sure how to make this work with Aurelia's property observing mechanisms.

Comment: I'm a little confused, could you describe what you want to do a little more. Converters are used in the view's binding attribute with a pipe like so `some-bindable-prop.bind="mybinding | myconverter"` beyond this what are you trying to achieve? A codepen or something would help a lot too.

Comment: It's not possible to specify the type of bindable properties in Aurelia. This means that I cannot do something like `<my-component disabled="false"></my-component>`, only `<my-component disabled.bind="false"></my-component>`. The first case will be a string. [An issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/347) talks about this more in-depth. I'm trying to create a decorator that will convert the property from string to boolean, so the value is consistent. I'm planning on having multiple converters and using them as `@valueConverter(BooleanConverter)`.

Comment: Sorry about the name, I didn't realize Aurelia already uses it.

Comment: The harder part is when you integrate with templating. If you can overcome it, that would be good.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I were trying to accomplish this, I start by copying the code for the `bindable` decorator, and then add my own code to it. It's located here: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/decorators.js

It also might be helpful to look at how the `observable` decorator does things: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/src/decorator-observable.js

It looks like you might have to get your hands pretty dirty to accomplish what you want.. That being said, if you are able to make it happen, we'd love for it to come back to the framework as a PR at some point!

Comment: I think it may be a lot easier to simply edit the `bindable` decorator to support this feature. I'll see what I can do and if it works, I'll submit a PR.

Comment: It very well might be. Hopefully you can figure that out. I'm rooting for you :-)